# xcode update to version 2395. ld compile problem occurs: computedAtomCount && "more atoms allocated than expected

Tags: c++

After I update xcode to new version in M1 Mac and then compile c++ by using make. the following problem occurs:

```
0  0x1010c81a0  __assert_rtn + 140
1  0x100f4fa8c  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<arm64>::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 4536
2  0x100f21d38  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<arm64>::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 148
3  0x100f8a4ac  ld::tool::InputFiles::makeFile(Options::FileInfo const&, bool) + 1468
4  0x100f8d360  ___ZN2ld4tool10InputFilesC2ER7Options_block_invoke + 56
5  0x1893941f4  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 20
6  0x1893a7954  _dispatch_apply_invoke + 224
7  0x1893941b4  _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8  0x1893a5a04  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 680
9  0x1893a6104  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
10  0x189554324  _pthread_wqthread + 228
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/smr_dense_SL-2022-09-14-165143.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_file->_atomsArrayCount == computedAtomCount && "more atoms allocated than expected"), function parse, file macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 2061.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [smr_dense_SL] Error 1
```

Comment: Long shots, but did you clean the build first, and update the command line tools? (BTW, 2395 looks like a pretty odd version number – XCode version 14.0 has build number 14A309. What exactly has version 2395?)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732838/more-atoms-allocated-than-expected-gcc-12#comment130199721_73732838

Comment: I think this has been fixed in the yesterday's release.

Comment: @molbdnilo 2395 comes from the command `xcode-select -v` in command line

Answer (score 12):

**Update: Download 14.1 beta 3 or higher to resolve the issue. Otherwise, read below.**

The issue is with XCode 14.0 version, which I have tested and confirmed.

Downgrade your command line tools version to 13.4 and it will be resolved.

First download command line tools from the apple developers site and install it: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13.4/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13.4.dmg

You can change the version using the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

To check the version of currently selected xcode command line tools, use the following command:

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
```

Make sure it is 13.4.

There are multiple GitHub discussions around this:

https://github.com/iains/gcc-12-branch/issues/6
https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3659

Comment: Thanks!!! , I solve this by using clang installed via homebrew and putting the following into makefile. 
```
 CC="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang"
 CXX_UNIX="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++"
 LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
 CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1"
 AR="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-ar"
 LD="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang"
```

Comment: I have MacOs Big Sure and clt 13.4 is not supported. What version of gcc/clt should I use to work around the bugs?
now: gcc-12 + Xcode 13.2.1 problem at linking stage.
answer: Downgrade to gcc-11 solve problem

Comment: I tried gcc-11 (from homebrew) and saw the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Link doesn't work. Here is a working link: [https://developer.apple.com/download/all/](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/). Download 14.1 beta 3 or higher to fix this issue.

Comment: Just installed 14.2 and still see this issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

there is another way to solve this problem

```
#pragma GCC optimize("O2")
```

and wait untill Xcode solve this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eh in many cases that is not enough or accepted, explain the exact flag that creates the problem O3 does some very good improvements we might not want to lose

Comment: @Spyros Mourelatos
that's correct , but if u need wan't to solve the hole problems , u need to reinstall Xcode 14.1