# More atoms allocated than expected gcc-12

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, g++

whenever I try to "g++ file.cpp" I get the following error message,

```
0  0x1008a81a0  __assert_rtn + 140
1  0x10072fa8c  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<arm64>::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 4536
2  0x100701d38  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<arm64>::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 148
3  0x10076a4ac  ld::tool::InputFiles::makeFile(Options::FileInfo const&, bool) + 1468
4  0x10076d360  ___ZN2ld4tool10InputFilesC2ER7Options_block_invoke + 56
5  0x18c69c1f4  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 20
6  0x18c6b0f8c  _dispatch_apply_invoke_and_wait + 224
7  0x18c6b026c  _dispatch_apply_with_attr_f + 1152
8  0x18c6b047c  dispatch_apply + 108
9  0x10076d1f4  ld::tool::InputFiles::InputFiles(Options&) + 616
10  0x1006ef6c0  main + 552
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/a.out-2022-09-15-161557.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_file->_atomsArrayCount == computedAtomCount && "more atoms allocated than expected"), function parse, file macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 2061.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
➜  ~
```

I tried unistalling and reinstalling gcc, Xcode CLI, and Xcode. Nothing seems to fix it!

Note: The code compiles on Xcode, I only face this problem with gcc.

Comment: That is a broken linker. It is not directly an issue with the compiler. Does this happen with a simple hello world program or what kind of contents of `file.cpp` are you testing with? How did you install GCC?

Comment: @user17732522 
Simple programs usually compile okay. This particular problem can be fixed by using auto instead of vector<int> in a function, or by using std::cout instead of printf in the same function.

I installed gcc using brew.

Comment: Then please show a [mre] for the issue. In particular `auto` instead of `vector<int>` having an effect sounds very dubious, because `auto` is going to be replaced by the type at compilation time and the linker will never see any difference.

Comment: My colleagues and I are also experiencing this error after a recent XCode update. There appears to be some conflict between XCode and gcc installed via homebrew, but we're unable to find the conflict or isolate gcc from XCode.

Comment: This seems to be a widespread issue. I suggest you check whether it has already been reported to Apple and have a look whether you can find an open bug report (I don't know where Apple tracks these or whether they are public). Having the linker crash with an assertion failure is in itself a bug.

Comment: @user17732522
I'll try to file a bug report, thank you.

Comment: @brady I assume gcc must be using some XCode binaries underneath.

Comment: I have the same error, just install gcc-12 via homebrew. Compile a library using cmake from CLI and the error appears. Any resolution?

Comment: @Bharata, Someone suggested downgrading xcode to 13.4, that seems to fix it for now!

Comment: @Tahuti I don't install xcode at all. I compile that from terminal.