# Xcode 14.0 GCC-12 Linker Issue

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, ld

My Mac updated Xcode to version 14.0. After installing the new command line tools I started running into issues with the version of `ld` that it ships with. More specifically I have a project I compile with the g++-12 compiler (installed via homebrew) and the linker bombs when I try to compile anything with the following output:

```
[  0%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libeckit.dylib
0  0x10675fffa  __assert_rtn + 139
1  0x10659328d  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86_64>::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 4989
2  0x106583f8f  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86_64>::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 207
3  0x1065fa9d4  ld::tool::InputFiles::makeFile(Options::FileInfo const&, bool) + 2036
4  0x1065fdfa0  ___ZN2ld4tool10InputFilesC2ER7Options_block_invoke + 48
5  0x7ff80248534a  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 8
6  0x7ff8024968f5  _dispatch_apply_invoke + 213
7  0x7ff802485317  _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8  0x7ff802494c0c  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 673
9  0x7ff80249525c  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 160
10  0x7ff802638f8a  _pthread_wqthread + 256
A linker snapshot was created at:
        /tmp/libeckit.dylib-2022-09-15-112741.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_file->_atomsArrayCount == computedAtomCount && "more atoms allocated than expected"), function parse, file macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 2061.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libeckit.dylib] Error 1
```

I've tried reinstalling all the home-brew packages but this didn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a recent linker bug, I have found a few references, and I think [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714336/xcode-update-to-version-2395-ld-compile-problem-occurs-computedatomcount-m/73765819#73765819) describes a downgrade of xcode/command line tools to work around it until the bug is fixed in xcode 14.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have an answer but I'm seeing a similar problem with GCC-11.

```
0  0x1024dcffa  __assert_rtn + 139
1  0x10231028d  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86_64>::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 4989
2  0x102300f8f  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86_64>::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 207
3  0x10234e404  archive::File<x86_64>::makeObjectFileForMember(archive::File<x86_64>::Entry const*) const + 1268
4  0x10234da8b  archive::File<x86_64>::File(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, archive::ParserOptions const&) + 1035
5  0x10234cc72  archive::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, archive::ParserOptions const&) + 146
6  0x102377c8e  ld::tool::InputFiles::makeFile(Options::FileInfo const&, bool) + 2734
7  0x10237afa0  ___ZN2ld4tool10InputFilesC2ER7Options_block_invoke + 48
8  0x7ff80418134a  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 8
9  0x7ff8041928f5  _dispatch_apply_invoke + 213
10  0x7ff804181317  _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  0x7ff804190c0c  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 673
12  0x7ff80419125c  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 160
13  0x7ff804334f8a  _pthread_wqthread + 256
A linker snapshot was created at:
        /tmp/SendData-2022-09-17-202519.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_file->_atomsArrayCount == computedAtomCount && "more atoms allocated than expected"), function parse, file macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 2061

Details of my OS:
nd Mac OS with following details.
System Version: macOS 12.6 (21G115)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 21.6.0
 Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro15,1
      Processor Name: 8-Core Intel Core i9
      Processor Speed: 2.4 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 8
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 16 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 32 GB
      System Firmware Version: 1731.140.2.0.0 (iBridge: 19.16.16067.0.0,0)
      OS Loader Version: 540.120.3~22
```

Comment: Finally, I'm able to reproducibly address the above issue on macOS Monterey by upgrading Xcode to Version 14.2 (14C18) from 14.1. Everywhere I faced the above issue got automagically resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem with GCC-11, but upgraded via brew to GCC-12 in hopes that it would solve the problem.  No joy.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. It looks like a "I'm having this problem too" comment / a "I tried this and it doesn't work" comment.